# Finding limit of the expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}$  $[1+{n \choose 1}k + {n \choose 2}k^2+\dots+{n \choose d}k^d]^{\frac{1}{n}}$. $k$ and $d$ are independent of $n$.

Is it convergent? If so, how and what is the limit?

Comment: $d = n-1$, isn't it?

Comment: $d$ is independent of $n$.

Comment: Should it be ${n \choose d}k^d$ instead of ${n \choose 1}k^d$?

Comment: Yes Alfred Chern. Sorry. I have edited.

Comment: @Fractas So $d$ is a fixed constant, not larger than $n$ and independent of $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $1+{n \choose 1}k + {n \choose 2}k^2+\dots+{n \choose d}k^d$ is a polynomial of n with index $d$, so 
$$1<1+{n \choose 1}k + {n \choose 2}k^2+\dots+{n \choose d}k^d<an^d$$
for some positive constant $a$ when $n$ large enough, then
$$1\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[1+{n \choose 1}k + {n \choose 2}k^2+\dots+{n \choose d}k^d]^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(an^d)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$

Comment: How does this come out :$$\sum\limits_{i = 0}^d {C_n^i{k^i}}  < a{n^d}$$

Comment: @ShineMic: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^ d C_n^i k^i}{n^d}$ exist

Comment: Gotcha! Thx a lot:)